# Portrait Orientated Monitor Taking Landscape Orientated Input - Linux Fedora

Tags: fedora, touchscreen, peripherals

I am attempting to set up a touchscreen monitor on a computer I just installed the newest version of Fedora on.

Touch Screen Monitor: Acer - T-Series 23" IPS LED HD Touch-Screen Monitor

Computer: Lenovo H515s (57321932) Desktop, 1.5GHz AMD A4-5000, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD

Computer came with pre-installed Windows 8.

I partitioned 100 gb to my Fedora install and installed with no errors from a usb set up with LiveUSB.

The problem:

My monitor is orientated portrait. I open the display settings on fedora and change the display to the right 90 degrees. Everything looks fine, except that my touch inputs are being given as if the screen is still in landscape orientation. I am able to touch the correct buttons on the screen if I touch in the spot I know they are on the landscape orientation.

Is this a problem with a driver? Or just some compatibility issue with the hardware and Fedora?

This monitor worked fine in Windows 8 set to portrait mode. Windows 8 is still installed, and if I boot it up, it still works fine in portrait mode.